# Failed to instantiate object when objects structure change in Mongo DB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, instantiation

I have Spring boot application and mongo db to persist objects. Objects can change and I write all these objects to one collection in mongo. But with time I get an error -

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [SomeObject] using constructor public...

when trying to do some requests to mongo db from my Spring application. **All errors disappear when I clean the database and write new objects.** Why I get error? Maybe I have to do some updating in mongo db when I change the object structure? Sorry, I can't describe exactly how to reproduce this error. Maybe someone can say what happened.

Answer (score 0):

When some ancient object arrives, the application cannot deserialize it through the constructor with all fields and tries through NoArgs ... Therefore, I added this constructor.
So when objects change, care must be taken to make it possible to create new objects from older